# add security headers in NGINX while using fastcgi caching

Tags: security, nginx, header, fastcgi

I am using nginx with fastcgi cache. I want to use security headers on my site. I have already added add header field in my virtual host configurations but I can not get any headers unless I  disable add_header X-fastcgi cache $upstream cache status in my fastcgi_main.conf  file.
virualhost file :

```
    }
   include /etc/nginx/bots.d/blockbots.conf;
   include /etc/nginx/bots.d/ddos.conf;
   include /etc/nginx/skip_cache.conf ;
   include /etc/nginx/purge_location.conf ;
   include /etc/nginx/gzip_location.conf ;
   include /etc/nginx/security_wp.conf;
        add_header Referrer-Policy 'origin';
        add_header "X-Frame-Options: sameorigin" always;
    location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    include "/etc/nginx/customfastcgi" ;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    proxy_send_timeout 300;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    send_timeout 300;
#    underscores_in_headers on;
client_max_body_size 256M;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_main.conf ;
    }

}
```

FASTCGI_main.conf

````
        fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_cache phpcache;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 1m;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 301 1m;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 302 1m;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 307 1m;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 404 1m;
        fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_503;
        fastcgi_cache_min_uses 1;
        fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD;
        fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
       add_header X-FastCGI-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    ```

RESULT:
curl -I https://dev-kuhicbury.$domain
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Date: Fri, 09 Oct 2020 11:39:35 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
rel="https://api.w.org/"
X-FastCGI-Cache: HIT
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've stepped onto a very common configuration pitfall of the `add_header` directive.
Similar to all other array-like directives in NGINX, it is *only* inherited, if there is no other `add_header` in the current context.

The typical solution is to copy-paste (through inevitable duplication), the desired headers in a specific location:

In `FASTCGI_main.conf`:

```
        fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_cache phpcache;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 1m;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 301 1m;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 302 1m;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 307 1m;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 404 1m;
        fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_503;
        fastcgi_cache_min_uses 1;
        fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD;
        fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
        add_header X-FastCGI-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
        add_header Referrer-Policy 'origin';
        add_header "X-Frame-Options: sameorigin" always;
```

This unintuitive behavior of NGINX has been a source of trouble for many.

Here are some modules of interest, which address the same issue (as in, "better `add_header`"):

- [ngx_headers_more](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module)
- [ngx_security_headers](https://github.com/GetPageSpeed/ngx_security_headers), more applicable to your case