# Nginx: How to set headers for all the files under a specific folder

Tags: nginx, browser-cache, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

So Let's say I have my application where files are under

https://myapp.com/v1/assets/images/*.jpg

and

https://myapp.com/v1/assets/js/*.jpg

I would like to add a rule that would set no-cache headers to anything under /assets

I believe what I can for now do is

```
 location ~ .*assets/js/.*$ {
  add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=0, no-store";
}

location ~ .*assets/images/.*$ {
  add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=0, no-store";
}
```

But that seems not working plus if I have many other folders under assets, I will need to add a separate rule.

Can I group everything in a pattern so that anything under /assets/* would have that header?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done via `map` directive:

```
map $uri $cache_control {
    ~/assets/(images|js)/    "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
}
server {
    ...
    add_header Cache-Control $cache_control;
    ...
}
```

If your URI won't match the regex, `$cache_control` variable would have an empty value and nginx won't add that header to its response. However there are other nginx directives that could affect `Cache-Control` header, i.e. `expires`. If you have something like `expires <value>;` in your config, you can use two `map` blocks:

```
map $uri $cache_control {
    ~/assets/(images|js)/    "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
}
map $uri $expire {
    ~/assets/(images|js)/    off;
    default                  <value>;
}
server {
    ...
    expires $expire;
    add_header Cache-Control $cache_control;
    ...
}
```

And take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64279365/add-security-headers-in-nginx-while-using-fastcgi-caching/64280522#64280522) answer to not be surprised with `add_header` directive behavior.