# Unable to set Cache-Control in NGINX Ubuntu

Tags: nginx, cache-control, nginx-location

I have a website on an EC2 instance with NGINX and Ubuntu 18.0.4. I have setup the server block for the site the site is loading correctly. I have also enabled caching for images, javascript and css files.

I want to exclude certain paths from getting cached and I tried some config examples available on the internet. None  of them are working and I am getting a 404 error for the locations that I am trying to exclude.

My server block is as follows:

```
# Expires map
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   max;
    application/javascript     max;
    ~image/                    max;
    ~font/                     max;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    expires $expires;

 location /path1/ {
    add_header Cache-Control "private";
 }

 location /path2/subpath1/ {
    add_header Cache-Control "private";
 }

 location /path2/subpath2/ {
    add_header Cache-Control "private";
 }

 location /path2/subpath3/ {
    add_header Cache-Control "private";
 }
}
```

The paths (path1, path2) which I have tried to exclude from caching are returning a 404 not found error. Can someone please help?

Comment: please share the full configuration for the server context we are talking about. I can't see a single `proxy_pass` `try_files` or `proxy_pass`. What should NGINX display in this case different than a 404.

Comment: The provided configuration fragment isn't enough to explain why it is happened, but I think solution should be similar to these answers: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64287782/7121513), [2](https://serverfault.com/a/1093097/498657).

Comment: @TimoStark - I am new to NGINX config and this is the config that I currently have. Can you please guide as to how a sample / working config should look like?

Comment: @IvanShatsky - Thanks. That was helpful. But I still don't know if my server block config is correct or missing some key setup. Do you have a working example to share?

Comment: @ShoumikDas Both answers I'm referring to has working examples. You don't need to use any additional locations, just add the `map` block for the `Cache-Control` header value to be derived from the `$uri` variable.