# nginx: disable cache for everything except all png/svg and one js file

Tags: nginx

I'm using nginx to serve a documentation website that changes frequently. For this reason I decided to drop cache with the following:

```
add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
if_modified_since off;
expires off;
etag off;
proxy_no_cache 1;
proxy_cache_bypass 1;
```

However with this, for each page you are visiting on this site, it downloads each time an big js file (7mb) and all png/svg images, so I would like to drop cache for everything except for all png/svg and one js file that resides in the ROOT path of the project. Is possible with nginx?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use every cache-related directive you can find? Does it make sense? Are you using some backend web app via `proxy_pass`? If using only `Cache-Control` and `Expires` headers will be ok for you, you can use the technique described in these answers: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64287782/7121513), [2](https://serverfault.com/a/1093097/498657). The same can be used for the `proxy_no_cache` and `proxy_bypass` directives (which make sense only if you are using the `proxy_pass` one). However you can't use variables with the `if_modified_since` and `etag` directives.

Comment: I'm using ansible, so I have that file there with all cache-related directive that works everywhere. This is an html website without `proxy_pass`

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't use the `proxy_pass` directive, tuning `proxy_no_cache` and `proxy_bypass` parameters makes no sense, you can safely remove that part from you config. For everything else the following should be enough to cache only selected files while do not cache everything else.

This should be placed to the `http` context:

```
map $uri $cacheable {
    ~\.(?:pn|sv)g$    1;
    /script.js        1;
}
map $cacheable $cache_control {
    1        "public, max-age=31536000";
    default  "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0";
}
map $cacheable $expire {
    1        1y;
    default  off;
}
```

This should be placed at the `server` context instead of your current configuration snippet:

```
add_header Cache-Control $cache_control;
expires    $expire;
```

And take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64279365/add-security-headers-in-nginx-while-using-fastcgi-caching/64280522#64280522) answer to not be surprised with `add_header` directive behavior.